# Scaling Property in DFT

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, dft

In below image, we have scaling property of DFT, how the final equation is obtained from the above equation. That is how we are getting the scaling factor , $ \frac{1}{|ab|} $ in the final equation ? Please explain how we are getting $ \frac{1}{|ab|} $. Thank you

[image]

Equation 4.12 is given as
[image]

Comment: You'll have to read Eq. (4.12) to find out why!

Comment: the equation 4.12 is general DFT equation. See I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{m=0}^{M-1} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} f(am,bn)e^{-j \cdot 2\pi(\frac {k}{M} \cdot m + \frac {l}{N} \cdot n)} $  (let $m'=am, n'=bn$)

$=\sum\limits_{m'=0}^{(M-1)a} \sum\limits_{n'=0}^{(N-1)b} f(m',n')e^{-j \cdot 2\pi(\frac {k/a}{M} \cdot m' + \frac {l/b}{N} \cdot n')}$

($m'$, $n'$ with the incremental interval of $a$ and $b$ respectively)

Note that 
$\sum\limits_{m'=0}^{M-1} \sum\limits_{n'=0}^{N-1} f(m',n')e^{-j \cdot 2\pi(\frac {k/a}{M} \cdot m' + \frac {l/b}{N} \cdot n')}$
$=F(k/a,l/b)$

Here $m'$, $n'$ with the incremental interval of $1$, and the points $m$ and $n$ are evenly distributed on the circle, according to the symmetry, you have

$\sum\limits_{m'=0}^{(M-1)a} \sum\limits_{n'=0}^{(N-1)b} f(m',n')e^{-j \cdot 2\pi(\frac {k/a}{M} \cdot m' + \frac {l/b}{N} \cdot n')} = \frac {1}{|ab|}F(k/a,l/b)$

Comment: Thank you, one more doubt.. why the limits are becoming  (M-1)/a and (N-1)b ? need some explanation. I am not good at maths. sorry if this question is very silly..

Comment: It should be (M-1)a... I mis-typed the formula when using latex. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: we get (M-1)a because we are scaling in spatial domain and cancelling that effect by taking 1/|ab| in the final equation. Am I correct?  explain me this in text please.

Comment: You are correct. m=m'/a, if m ranges from 0 to M-1, m' will be 0 to a(M-1)

Comment: Thank you very much.. It helped me.. you are good.. you are helping students like me a lot.. spending time to answer and replying to our comments.. I have been following you for a month on this forum and you answer most of question here. THANK YOU again for your service. I want to be like you.. gaining knowledge and helping others with that knowledge by sharing it..

Comment: you are very welcome! Good luck on your study!

Answer (score 0):

But 1/ab is scaling the magnitude.
Here limits are for the indices.